# Language selector for subpages only

Tags: language

Have you seen any examples of websites using language selectors for select sub-pages only?

Target audience for the product are English speakers. However, they employ a lot of Spanish speaking people, therefore the careers pages within the website need translation.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is something I have never come across.

A few questions:

- Why is the only page to be in spanish the careers page?
- Why not the rest?
- What if their english isn't good enough to get to the careers page?

I don't see why the whole site wouldn't be available in the languages you need. If a user lands on the site looking for a job and realises the site isn't in the language they need, will they progress to the careers page or get there quickly? Is this something you know based on analytics or have tested that happens?

The platforms I work on, the entire site is available in the languages required based on our user base and target audience to help them get to where they need in their native language. This helps for the conversions we want them to achieve.

Comment: Those are all great questions to frame the discussion. The analytics indicate less than 1% Spanish speakers visiting the site. However 30% of applicants to job are Spanish speakers (this is for factory type work).

Comment: That is an interesting issue, would the 1% go up if there was a Spanish translation option and given that 30% of job applicants are Spanish speakers is that not reason enough to explore it?